# Do I have to set web farm for multiple web sites in the same IIS server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, redirect, iis-8.5, web-farm

I have multiple web sites hosted in the same IIS 8.5.

The web sites names are same but different ports or http/https. For example,

1. http://www.mydemosite.com (using default port 80)
2. https://www.mydemosite.com (using default port 443)
3. http://www.mydemosite.com:5000 (using non-standard port 5000)
4. https://www.mydemosite.com:5001 (using non-standard port 5001)

All of them are in the IIS server, is that okay or a good idea or messed up? I have redirect requirements from http to https, say 1 to 2 and 3 to 4.

Comment: You showed four site bindings, but how many sites do you have exactly? The common understand of "web farm" means multiple servers in the same cluster, so talking about "web farm" when you only have a single server is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to run multiple sites on a single IIS server. I've seen servers hosting several hundred sites.

It all comes down to how busy your sites are, how many requests the server hardware can handle.

A web farm, using multiple servers for a single web site usually only used to high load sites or for redundancy.

Using different ports is a bit uncommon these days, you just use different host names instead.